# Angular 8 Router Does Not Render Various Components

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-router

I am building a CRUD app and I want to separate various component's routes by object type. The first series of routes work perfectly. However, the third, fourth, fifth, and sixth routes are failing to render various child routes.

Here is my routes array:

```
const routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'obj-type1',
        children: [
          { path: 'all', component: ViewObjType1Component },
          { path: 'new', component: CreateObjType1Component },
          { path: ':id', component: ViewObjType1Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType1Component },
          // * { path: ':id/obj-type2', component: ViewObjType2ByClientContractIDComponent },
          // * { path: ':id/obj-type3', component: ViewObjType3ByClientContractIDComponent },
          // * { path: ':id/obj-type4', component: ViewObjType4ByClientContractIDComponent },
          // * { path: ':id/obj-type5', component: ViewObjType5ByClientContractIDComponent },
          // * { path: ':id/obj-type6', component: ViewObjType6ByClientContractIDComponent },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'obj-type2',
        children: [
          { path: 'all', component: ViewObjType2Component },
          { path: 'new', component: AssignObjType2Component },
          { path: ':id', component: ViewObjType2Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType2Component }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'obj-type3',
        children: [
          { path: 'all', component: ViewObjType3Component },
          { path: ':id', component: ViewObjType3Component },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'ObjType4',
        children: [
          // ** { path: 'all', ViewObjType4Component },
          // ** { path: 'new', GenerateObjType4Component },
          // ** { path: ':id', ViewObjType4Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType4Component },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'obj-type5',
        children: [
          // ** { path: 'all', ViewObjType5Component },
          // ** { path: 'new', CreateObjType5Component },
          // ** { path: ':id', ViewObjType5Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType5Component },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'obj-type6',
        children: [
          // ** { path: 'all', ViewObjType6Component },
          // ** { path: 'new', GenerateObjType6Component },
          // ** { path: ':id', ViewObjType6Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType6Component },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

My app.routing.ts file contains this reference to the above listed feature module:

```
        {
            path: 'feature-module',
            loadChildren: './feature_modules/feature-module/feature-module.module#FeatureModule'
        },
```

The routes marked "// * {}" break the entire router.

The routes marked "?? ** {}" do not break anything but do not render any components either.

I am not sure why this is happening. I have tried re-ordering the routes in the array. Perhaps I need a layout component attached to each /obj-typeN route that includes a  to render it's children?

Answer (score 0):

This was a very simple mistake. I forgot to write "component: " before referencing the components for the offending routes. The answer is to change:

```
{
        path: 'ObjType4',
        children: [
          // ** { path: 'all', ViewObjType4Component },
          // ** { path: 'new', GenerateObjType4Component },
          // ** { path: ':id', ViewObjType4Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType4Component },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'obj-type5',
        children: [
          // ** { path: 'all', ViewObjType5Component },
          // ** { path: 'new', CreateObjType5Component },
          // ** { path: ':id', ViewObjType5Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType5Component },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'obj-type6',
        children: [
          // ** { path: 'all', ViewObjType6Component },
          // ** { path: 'new', GenerateObjType6Component },
          // ** { path: ':id', ViewObjType6Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType6Component },
        ]
      }
```

to

```
{
        path: 'ObjType4',
        children: [
          // ** { path: 'all', component: ViewObjType4Component },
          // ** { path: 'new', component: GenerateObjType4Component },
          // ** { path: ':id', component: ViewObjType4Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType4Component },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'obj-type5',
        children: [
          // ** { path: 'all', component: ViewObjType5Component },
          // ** { path: 'new', component: CreateObjType5Component },
          // ** { path: ':id', component: ViewObjType5Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType5Component },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'obj-type6',
        children: [
          // ** { path: 'all', component: ViewObjType6Component },
          // ** { path: 'new', component: GenerateObjType6Component },
          // ** { path: ':id', component: ViewObjType6Component },
          { path: ':id/manage', component: ManageObjType6Component },
        ]
      }
```

This solution fixed all errors.